# Magento - adding custom block to the shipping methods page via module

Tags: php, jquery, magento

I am just starting out with Magento and I am still struggling to understand how layout system works.

I am trying to add a custom block of HTML to shipping methods part of checkout strictly by using code from my custom module (I dont want to make any changes to core files). I checked out checkout.xml and it looks like this is the block I am looking for to append my custom block to:

```
<block type="checkout/onepage_shipping_method_available" name="checkout.onepage.shipping_method.available" as="available" template="checkout/onepage/shipping_method/available.phtml"/>
```

My config file:

```
    <modules>
        <Brisqq_Cart>
            <version>0.1.0</version>    <!-- Version of module  -->
        </Brisqq_Cart>
    </modules>
    <frontend>
        <routers>
            <mymodule>
                <use>standard</use>
                <args>
                    <module>Brisqq_Cart</module>
                    <frontName>mymodule</frontName>
                </args>
            </mymodule>
        </routers>
         <layout>
            <updates>
                <mymodule>
                    <file>mymodule.xml</file> <!-- Our layout file name-->
                </mymodule>
            </updates>
         </layout>
    </frontend>
    <global>
        <blocks>
            <mymodule>
                <class>Brisqq_Cart_Block</class>
            </mymodule>
        </blocks>
    </global>
</config>
```

mymodule.xml:

```
<layout>
    <default>
        <reference name="checkout.onepage.shipping_method.available">  
            <block type="mymodule/mymodule" name="mymodule" template="mymodule.phtml" /> 
        </reference>
    </default>
</layout>
```

This is not working since nothing appears on checkout page, but I am sure I am missing something obvious, I just cant figure out what.
My second question that is closely related to the first one is how do I include my custom js and css to this specific page?
Last question, in case a magento wizard is reading this, how do I fire a jquery function AFTER shipping methods step is loaded? (Also from custom module, no core file changes.)
Thanks in advance!
PS. The code works if I put 'content' instead of `<reference name="checkout.onepage.shipping_method.available">` but then my custom block shows up on all page, and I want it to show only on checkout page.

Comment: What is the purpose of your custom block? If you are trying to make a custom shipping method available during checkout, you would go about that [a different way](https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2014/01/create-custom-shipping-methods-magento/).

Comment: I already have custom shipping method, I am trying to add custom block of HTML to it.

Comment: Okay, so does your shipping method already show up as one of the options, and you are trying to append a custom block to it in the list?

Comment: Yes, that's the case! It shows up, and I am trying to append my custom block to it.

Comment: I have copy of this tutorial shipping method, and it works. Now I need to append custom block to it. http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/create-a-custom-shipping-method-in-magento--cms-23747

Answer (score 0):

If I have understood the issue correctly, this is unfortunately a situation where you will not be able to insert a custom block into the document flow using only layout XML. The reason for this is because the `Mage_Checkout_Block_Onepage_Shipping_Method_Available` block doesn’t provide any insertion points that will automatically render child blocks in its default template `app/design/frontend/base/default/template/checkout/onepage/shipping_method/available.phtml`.

In order to append a custom block, you have a couple of options for overriding the template:

1. Copy the template from `base` theme into the same path under your store’s custom theme and edit it there (i.e. `app/design/frontend/custom/default/template/.../available.phtml`). That would be my preferred approach.
2. Use your extension to override the template path for that block to one inside your extension’s template directory.

> ```
> <checkout_onepage_index>
>     <reference name="checkout.onepage.shipping_method.available">
>         <action method="setTemplate"><template>mymodule/shipping_method/available.phtml</template></action>
>     </reference>
> </checkout_onepage_index>
> ```

In your version of the `available.phtml` template you can make any changes you need, including rendering any child blocks, calling helpers, etc.

Comment: The problem with this approach is that I am not suppoused to change/copy or do anything with any files outside my module. I managed to insert my custom block only with layout.xml in the same page with shipping methods. I should move my custom html block to the right spot with JS. In order to do this succesfully, I need to make my JS fires AFTER all magento JS.. Do you have any idea how do I make my custom JS fires after all magento prototype (and all other inline) js?